# I have custom uinavigation class. In that custom delegate method declared. How to access that method to view controller

Tags: swift

```
@objc  protocol MyDelegate {
    func buttonAction()
}

class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationController {

var delegte : MyDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRectMake(200, 10, 50, 30))
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "a.png"), forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "testing", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.navigationBar.addSubview(button)
}

func testing(){
    self.delegte?.buttonAction()
    print("Pavan")
}
```

If i press this button, testing is calling.

But in viewcontroller calling delegate method but giving error

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,MyDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "hi"
    let vc = CustomNavigationBar()
    vc.delegte = self
}

func buttonAction() {
    print("Tupale")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

would u mind to hint the error message?

updated:
In `CustomNavigationBar` class, you have to change `var delegte : MyDelegate?` to `var delegte : UIViewController?`.

then in `ViewController` class, you could set `self` which is an instance of UIViewController to the delegate of `vc`.

Have a try.